# Why are 48 bytes appended to Libsodium encrypted messages if nonce is 24 bits?

Tags: libsodium

When encrypting a string through the Libsodium secret box feature, the ciphertext is 48 bytes longer than the plain text message ...

I am wondering why this is ... since the nonce is only 24 bytes.

Comment: There should be a 16 byte MAC as well.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Thanks, I guess that answers it. Many thanks and my apologies for this n00b question ;) ... However 24 + 16 <> 48 .... Am I missing something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that $\operatorname{secretbox}$ has a $16$-byte MAC too. For reference, I've included $\operatorname{box}$ too.

$$
\operatorname{secretbox} : \text{24 nonce} + \text{0 xsalsa} + \text{16 poly1305}\\
\operatorname{box} : \text{32 curve25519} + \text{24 nonce} + \text{0 xsalsa} + \text{16 poly1305}
$$

However, the nonce is user-controlled and normally not included in the ciphertext overhead as it is usually never sent, often a protocol-level counter.

You say "secret box" but you mean the normal "box" which uses a public key. Your ciphertext is expanded with your $32$-byte ephemeral public key and the $16$-byte MAC.

Comment: Thx. So nonce = 24 bytes, mac = 16 bytes, chacha20_encrypt = 8 bytes ?

Comment: Chacha is a stream cipher with no padding. So no overhead. BTW: updated answer regarding the validity of counting nonces here.

Comment: apparently xsalsa is the default; not chacha.

Comment: Thanks. But 24 + 16 is still not equal to 48 ... So I am still missing something that's probably obvious ...

Comment: Hmm... Can you send some code?

Comment: I checked and you are right that in crypto_boxes ONLY 16 bytes are added after encryption ... The 48 bytes I talked about are relevant when using sodium_crypto_box_seal ....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74671/discussion-between-vincent-mertens-and-cypherfox).

Answer (score 1):

Sealed boxes: public key (32 bytes) + MAC (16 bytes).

The nonce is deterministic, as a new key pair is created for every message.